# fetch api and csrf token rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, fetch-api

I have a rails backend with devise authenticating.

I am trying to use fetch api, which fails with error message

`can't verify CSRF token`

here's the fetch code, and I really cannot find another corner to look for the problem, could you help?

```
body = JSON.stringify({
  email:'xya@gmail.com', 
  password: 'abcdef', 
})
headers= {
        'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      }
method = 'post'


fetch('/users/sign_in',{method,body, headers, credentials: 'same-origin' })
```

thank you!

Comment: I would just disable CSRF for JSON requests.

Answer (score -2):

I think your params in the `fetch` function is wrong. It should be something like this:

`fetch('/users/sign_in',{ method: method, body: body, headers: headers, credentials: 'same-origin' })`

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think it's fine because of ES6's object destructuring https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/

Comment: My answer 2 years ago was not relevant. A better solution is not to use `fetch` in this case, use `Rails.ajax` instead if you have rails_ujs enabled.